# Adding "Copy/Move To folder" to the left side in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp

Is it possible to add "Copy/Move To folder" options to the left side in Windows 10, just like in [Windows XP File and Folder Tasks?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbPSB.gif)

Answer (score 0):

### Until you can find a way to add these to the left side - here is a reg file that will add "Copy To folder..." and "Move To folder..." to your context menu.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; add both copy to folder and move to folder to context menu
; displayed when you right-click a file or a folder

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]

;add move to folder to context menu

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]